# AJAX post not working using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code in for my button element

```
<script> 
    $(document).on("click","#ajax-button", function () {
            var dataToSend = "balblabla";
                    $.post("http://example.com/admin/sitemap/get_categories", dataToSend, function(data) {
                      alert(data);
                 });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this code in my controller:

```
public function getcategories()
{
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
    echo(json_encode("test out"));
}
```

But it's not working at all ;(

What am I doing wrong? jQuery is loaded before. Thats not a problem.

Comment: `not working at all` - describe THAT. Error messages? Strange behavior?

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: json_encode(array('msg'=>"test out"));

Comment: Your controller method is `getcategories` and in jQuery you call `get_categories`. Maybe just a typo? It should be the same if you are using MVC

Comment: They don't necessarily need to be the same, you could set up route values

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your $.post should be $.getJSON because $.post shortcut does not tell jQuery that it expects json as response.

```
$.getJSON('path/to/controller/method', {data: data, to: to, send: send}, function(data)
{
   alert(data);
});
```

PHP Part

```
public function getcategories()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['foo'] = 'bar';
    //best give json_encode an array as input so you can do data.foo in js part

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are expecting json data from simple simple post request so it is not getting data please change your request to

```
var dataToSend = {};
$.getJSON("http://example.com/admin/sitemap/get_categories", dataToSend, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

or also you can try this it for better understand

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataToSend,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment:

In general your URL should consist `path-to-controller/controller` (to call index method) `or path-to-controller/method` to call some special method of controller.

In this example:

- **someController** is your controller
- **someMethod** is someController's method that you are calling

`$.post('someController/someMethod', {
    foo: "bar" // data to send
}, function(data){
    alert(data); // response
});`

and the PHP controller

```
<?php
class someController {
    public function someMethod(){
        echo "hello from someMethod";
    }
}
?>
```